# Angular variable not being displayed in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to refresh my knowledge of Angular, and I can't seem to understand a few concepts, the "controller as" pattern doesn't seem to be working, for example, even though it seems to be much more simple than `$scope`.

I can't get a simple variable to show up in my HTML.

Here are two pieces of code in question:

**app.js**

```
angular
    .module('routerApp', [''])
    .controller('mainController', function () {
        'use strict';
        var vm = this;
        vm.bigMessage = 'A smooth sea never made a skilled sailor';
    })
```

**index.html** (stripped down heavily)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="container" ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
        <h1>{{ main.bigMesssage }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The interesting thing is that the browser doesn't even render `"{{ main.bigMessage }}"`, instead it shows nothing. Yet, in the source code there is the `{{ ... }}` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had added `''` in dependency array bracket which is wrong Angular is going to search for dependency with name  `''` & obiviously there would not be any dependancy find with that name & that why angular is throwing `$injector` error in console. , as you don't have any dependency, it should be `[]`

**Code**

```
angular
.module('routerApp', []) //<--change here
.controller('mainController', function () {
    'use strict';
    var vm = this;
    vm.bigMessage = 'A smooth sea never made a skilled sailor';
})
```

Also you have had typo in `{{main.bigMesssage}}` here `bigMesssage` should be `bigMessage` then it would become

```
{{main.bigMesssage}}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/F4dKA2G2fQWXMMhHCkpX?p=preview)

Comment: thanks pankajparkar! I've been actually trying to add and remove things there, and finally forgot to remove the quote marks, however, that wasn't the problem as I had tried both ways.

I can't even believe, I've been spending the last hour trying to find a... typo. My eyes are probably too tired for this already, thanks for spotting my mistake.

Comment: @zcserei that is the problem..check my updated description..you also had typo on html.. Glad to help you.. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 1):

you have written everything is right except your bigmessage variable spell

```
 <body class="container" ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
        <h1>{{ main.bigMessage }}</h1>
    </body>
```

controller

```
angular
    .module('routerApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', function () {
        var vm = this;
        this.bigMessage = 'A smooth sea never made a skilled sailor';
    })
```

check this out fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjwov6f1/1/

It was not finding your variable that why it was not showing anything

for more learning go through this link :https://thinkster.io/egghead/experimental-controller-as-syntax